# Why $[F(X)\leq G(z)] \bigcap [G^{-1}[F(X)] > z]$ is a subset of $F(X)=G(z)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> If $F(X)<G(z)$ implies $G^{-1}[F(X)]\leq z$, then $[F(X)\leq G(z)] \cap [G^{-1}[F(X)] > z]$,  is a subset of $F(X)=G(z)$.

I can't understand how does this statement hold, [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/100319/30971).

Comment: Is $G$ monotonically increasing? Is it strictly so, or not?

Comment: @robjohn, $G$ was assumed to be monotonically increasing (though not necessarily strictly) in that question. Though DanielFischer showed without that condition [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15811986#15811986).

Comment: Given the hypothesis, it turns out it doesn't matter. The question is simply a matter of complements and inclusions. Sorry for adding extra complication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$[G^{-1}[F(X)]\gt z]$ is the complement of $[G^{-1}[F(X)]\le z]$, which, by the hypothesis, contains $[F(X)\lt G(z)]$, which is the complement of $[F(X)\ge G(z)]$. Therefore,
$$
[G^{-1}[F(X)]\gt z]\subset F(X)\ge G(z)]
$$
and the conclusion follows; that is,
$$
\begin{align}
[F(X)\le G(z)]\cap[G^{-1}[F(X)]\gt z]&\subset [F(X)\le G(z)]\cap[F(X)\ge G(z)]\\
&=[F(X)=G(z)]
\end{align}
$$